# RecyclerView and DiffUtil - A Concurrency Nightmare

Tags: android, concurrency, android-recyclerview, diff, android-support-library

[The documentation for `DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) suggests generating the `DiffUtil.DiffResult` on a background thread because of potential long calculation times. This seems like a bad idea to me, because that thread could be operating on stale data in a situation like the following (assuming `list` access is thread safe):

1. Add data to `list` and notify adapter
2. Need to replace `list` with `newList` which would have a diff of some additions and some removals
3. Call `DiffUtil.calculateDiff` in the background and get the `DiffResult` for `list` and `newList`, and post a message to the main thread that will use `newList` and call `DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo`
4. Before that message is handled, the user takes an action on the main thread that causes mutations to `list`
5. The message is handled, `newList` is set to be the new data source and `DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo` is run causing an inconsistent view of the underlying data + a loss of any mutations since the `DiffResults` were calculated

Well that's no good, so let's change starting from step 3:

3. Set `newList` as the new data source, call `DiffUtil.calculateDiff` in the background and get the `DiffResult` for `list` and `newList`, and post a message to the main thread that will call `DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo`
4. Before that message is handled, the user takes an action on the main thread that causes mutations to `newList`, and notifies adapter, causing an inconsistent view of data because `DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo` hasn't been called yet

There are more variations on this, but none are good. It seems like the only way to reliably use `DiffUtil` with a large dataset and changeset is to either disable or queue all updates until `DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo` is called.

Am I missing something that would make the above false?

Comment: first of all, how many items do you have? if it is not couple of thousands, why to worry?

Comment: @pskink as the documentation states: `1000 items and 200 modifications without moves: 13.54 ms, median: 13.36 ms`. 1000 items is not that much. Taking 13.54 ms to do that leaves us with 2.5 ms to do all the other work for that frame, or we will have a dropped frame. 2.5 ms is not a lot of time.

Comment: ok so use `dispatchUpdatesTo(ListUpdateCallback updateCallback)`, and not `dispatchUpdatesTo(Adapter adapter)`, that way you will control how your updates are handled (you can skip updates on the items that was changed by the user in the meantime)

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare to me. Now I have to diff the diff and what was happening while it was being diffed.

Comment: how many updates the user can do manually in 16ms?

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is if there is a huge update that will take ~16 ms (or much more). Doing this on the main thread will block it and cause 1 or more frames to drop. Doing it on a background thread can now take much longer than 16 ms (thread suspension, etc..). It also doesn't have to be from the user. Updates can come from the network, or system behavior.

Comment: In my own usage, I have immutable data sets instead of modifying a single list. Then, I combine it with rx java. 
`listDataChange.observeOn(backgroundThread).switchMap(computeDiff).observeOn(mainThread).subscribe(applyTheChange);`

Answer (score 3):

I ended up stacking updates to manage user interaction during DiffUtil calculations and still accessing dataset in Main Thread only.

I wrote it there: https://geoffreymetais.github.io/code/diffutil-threading/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on BatchingListUpdateCallback. It is the class, wich is wrapped the main callback and when multi change on list occured, the batchingListCallback will notify only once the main callback.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/BatchingListUpdateCallback.html

**EDIT**

I am sorry my answer is not correct.

I looked in the source code DiffUtil. and I see, that the BatchingListUpdateCallback is used in `dispatchUpdatesTo` method anyway.

```
 public void dispatchUpdatesTo(ListUpdateCallback updateCallback) {
        final BatchingListUpdateCallback batchingCallback;
        if (updateCallback instanceof BatchingListUpdateCallback) {
            batchingCallback = (BatchingListUpdateCallback) updateCallback;
        } else {
            batchingCallback = new BatchingListUpdateCallback(updateCallback);
            // replace updateCallback with a batching callback and override references to
            // updateCallback so that we don't call it directly by mistake
            //noinspection UnusedAssignment
            updateCallback = batchingCallback;
        }
```

But as vector for the right way this could be useful :)

Comment: Interesting. So when the new list comes in we wrap the adapter with `BatchListUpdateCallback` and dispatch the DiffUtils results to it. There are still concurrency issues, but this would make a potential solution simpler to implement.